# Customer uses outlook and scheduling assistant to create teams meeting -- my calendar on Google Workspace does not show up - how to add my calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar

My customer is an employee of a MNC that use outlook and teams.

Whenever they schedule a meeting, they will add emails of the people they want to invite on outlook and they press the scheduling assistant. Then they can see everyone's calendar and find a suitable date time.

My customer can see the calendar of their colleagues. but they cannot see mine. I am using my Google Workspace calendar.

Is this something my customer IT admin need to do to allow my calendar to show up on the scheduling assistant?

What do I need to do to make this happen?

Here are the screenshots on my customer view

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The free/busy information is available for exchange account, as you are not in their organization, so they can't see that.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-an-outlook-calendar-with-other-people-353ed2c1-3ec5-449d-8c73-6931a0adab88

Answer (score 0):

Google Workspace administrators could make that possible that users of Exchange Calendars and Google Calendar share their availability. Usually this is done for users that belongs to the same organization but there are some features that might have "whitelists" and other ways that people from different organizations could share and collaborate.

One possibility as end-user is that you contact your manager and / or Google Workspace administrator to talk about this. Review the following to prepare yourself for this [Use both Exchange & Google calendars](https://support.google.com/a/topic/2798684?hl=en&ref_topic=9201).

Another possibility is that you make your free/busy information public and share your calendar with your customer. For details see [Share your calendar with someone](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en).